# Problems with vba discrimination

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a simple iteration loop that goes through each row of a workbook and reads the value in the first cell. Using the instring function of vba I determine whether or not the cell contains certain characters and if the criteria is met it either deletes or preserves the row. When I run this code, however, there are two cells that are spelled and formatted identically to each other, but one is deleted and one is saved. The cells in question contain the text (CJ 20210526) - Merlin FLIR Calibration. I have included the code for reference, because it is not very long and after scouring it multiple times I cannot find the issue. I don't understand how two cells that are exactly the same can be treated so disparately.

[Filter Code in VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUK8M.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8967612)

Comment: Why not paste the code as text? No one wants to write the text... !

Comment: By deleting the rows in the range you are examining you are changing the scope of what you examine.  The control variable for the loop does not know that you have deleted a row so does not adjust for the deletion.  This is a very common issue that is encountered by novice users of VBA when deleting items from collections.  As stated below you need to delete from the end of the range so that you don't affect the rows that are yet to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the code **backwards**.

Replace:

```
For x=1 to last_row
```

by:

```
For x=last_row to 1 Step -1
```

Also dim x as Long

*(there may be other errors)*